# Download (user) uploaded files django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my webapplications users can upload files (pdf's, ms-docs etc). I store the files in /media/, but I cannot seem to find a way to make the files downloadable again on the website (for other users).

This is the function in views.py that handles the upload form:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            resourceupload = form.save(commit=False)
            resourceupload.uploadedBy = request.user
            resourceupload.upload_date = timezone.now()
            resourceupload.save()
            return redirect('course', pk=resourceupload.course.pk)
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render(request, 'main/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

and this is the associated template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="post-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.title.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.title }}</td>
                </tr>
                <!--<tr>
                    <td>{{ form.major.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td id="majorcs" >{{ form.major }}</td>
                </tr>-->
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.course.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td id="coursejs">{{ form.course }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button type="button" onclick="window.document.location='{% url "addcourse" %}'"}>Add Course</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.resourcetype.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.resourcetype }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.resourcefile.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.resourcefile }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-blog pull-right">SAVE</button>
        </form>
```

The uploading goes fine, but I cannot seem to find a way to make the resourcefile downloadble.

This is a snippet from the template where I have a list of the resources that can be downloaded:

```
                {% for res in resources%}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{res.resourcetype}}</th>
                    <td>{{res.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{res.uploadedBy}}</td>
                    <td><a href="">{{res.resourcefile}}</a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

The idea is that users can download the file when they click on res.resourcefile

Comment: try to add `{{res.resourcefile.url}}` to `href` (in this line: `<td><a href="">{{res.resourcefile}}</a></td>`)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I feel like such a noob right now haha. I was trying thing that were very complex, when the solution is soo easy haha.